# chrome extension get original http response content

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm a newbie of chrome extension and coding a chrome extension.
Jsonview extension is good extension that prettify json response.
But when the json response content include html tag(,). it won't pretty it.
That I want to investigate this situation.
I fount that jsonview pretty the json response from 'document.body.innerText'.
The response should be valid json string. but 'document.body.innerText' is destroy by chrome and not valid json string.
That's the reason jsonview can't prettify.
So I want to get the original http response content(the valid json string).
Any one know how to get the original http content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hard code the jsonview source code and solve my issue.
**MODIFY**

```
function load() {
    var child, data;
    var tx = document.body.innerHTML;
    tx = tx.substring(0, tx.lastIndexOf("}"));
    if (document.body && (document.body.childNodes[0] && document.body.childNodes[0].tagName == "PRE" || document.body.children.length == 0)) {
        child = document.body.children.length ? document.body.childNodes[0] : document.body;
        data = extractData(child.innerText);
        if (data)
            init(data);
    }
    else if(tx.charAt(0) == "{" && tx.charAt(tx.length-1) == "}") {
        data = extractData(tx);
        if (data)
            init(data);
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL**

```
function load() {
    var child, data;
    if (document.body && (document.body.childNodes[0] && document.body.childNodes[0].tagName == "PRE" || document.body.children.length == 0)) {
        child = document.body.children.length ? document.body.childNodes[0] : document.body;
        data = extractData(child.innerText);
        if (data)
            init(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the raw HTTP content from JSONView, go to the options page and click the second checkbox that states "Use safe method to parse HTTP response(*)". The asterisk states: "safe method forces the browser to send an extra HTTP request to get the raw HTTP content".

[image]

Comment: useless. I look into the jsonview source code. it fetch the http response content by 'document.body.innerText' which is already modify by the browser. because the json response include the html tag(DOM tag). That browser treat it as DOM.